# JSON callback function only works with a text file

Tags: php, jquery, json

Does any one know why the call back only works with a text file

PHP

```
<?php include("alan.php"); ?>

<?php
$rows=array();
mysql_select_db('news') or die(mysql_error());
//echo "Connected to Database";<?php 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos") 
or die(mysql_error());  

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {    
    $rows[]=$row;
} 
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

This outputs:

```
[{"name":"photo1.jpg","id":"1"},{"name":"photo2.jpg","id":"2"},{"name":"photo3.jpg","id":"3"},{"name":"photo4.jpg","id":"4"}]
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#photos').click(function(){
        $.getJSON('photo_get.php',function(data){ /**Changing this to a text file works ????**/
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                alert("Data"    + val.name);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you format your code a little?  Tip: put 4 spaces in front of the line you want formatted as code.  It's a little hard to read here.

Comment: what if you fly an alert just to see if the callback fires at all?

Answer (score 3):

have you tried setting the content type in the php page?

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
?>
```

Comment: This should do it. The reason being is that PHP defaults to `text/html` output.

Comment: @user640707 ok... then could you go ahead and format your code like suggested, and then paste in the ACTUAL content that's being returned, if you haven't already.  I'm sure we'll get it sorted.

Comment: @user640707 I know you probably did... but just to double-check, did you put the header as the first thing in the page?

Comment: Found the cause it may help somone else all I had to do was erase the <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> from the top of the page. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user640707 From the top of the "photo_get.php" page?

Comment: Yep should have started with a blank page. Good old Dreamweaver

Comment: @user640707 Sorry then, I should have been more clear.  When I said "as the first thing on the page", that's what I meant.  The header needs to be sent before anything except whitespace.  Glad you got it sorted and that I could help a little!